# How to switch pane in Dolphin using keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, panel, dolphin

I'm a long time user of KDE [Dolphin](http://dolphin.kde.org) and love the pane mechanism. I know you can open/close pane using <kbd>F3</kbd>.

However, I can't find a shortcut to switch from one pane to another like Pycharm, Tmux or other application allow.

I know you can use the mouse, but I found it slow to move away from keyboard, locate cursor, move to right pane, click to focus and repeat while a single shortcut could do the same.

#### Question

- Is there such keyboard shortcut?
- How is it call?
- How do I configure
  it?

Comment: You can use `Tab` (and `Shift`+`Tab`) to cycle focused element, although this includes also the address bar.

Comment: @resc Thanks, as you noted it not really usable as the number of hit to do depend of the depth of the URL path :/

Comment: Seems like this [has been fixed](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=171743#c38) but not sure when it will be released

Comment: True. In the meantime, you can consider setting the address bar to `editable` (`F6` iirc). Then you should be able to cycle over it with a single `Tab`, although it's still 3 `Tab`'s per split.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dolphin version `17.08.3`

There is an option is `Settings > Configure Dolphin… > General` to use Tab to switch between panes:

[image: Dolphin]

Comment: is `tab` the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key or the feature?

Comment: Tab key on keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Konqueror is quite close to dolphin in terms of user experience. You could run konqueror, go to settings > Load View Profile > Midnight commander. It will automatically split in half, you can use tab / shift-tab to switch between panes, plus you have an extra konsole at the bottom. You also get a green indicator below each pane to show which one has the focus.

[image]

As a side note, I like how konqueror shows a preview of PDF document directly in the pane. You can then Alt-left to go back in history and return to folder view.

[image]

Comment: question is specific to Dolphin not konqueror