# Preview Pane for PDF Documents in File Manager

Tags: pdf, file-manager

Is there a program (e.g., file manager or PDF viewer) that provides a split view having a folder view and preview pane for PDF documents (ideally with the ability to scroll through the document like the preview pane in Windows 7)?

I have 100's of PDF documents that I need to preview rapidly. The file names are not helpful because they are auto-generated. I have used various file managers that generate thumbnails of the first page, but the thumbnails are too small to distinguish between documents. Additionally, it is often desirable to display subsequent pages in the same document.

I have tried batch opening the files in Foxit, but the number and size of files typically causes the program to crash.

I have tried Krusader, which spawns an external preview Krviewer window. This is not sufficient because it requires opening and closing the Krviewer for every file (similar to simply doing "open with..." an external program), which is slow.

Another StackExhange answer appears to show the desired behavior, but it does not appear to function in the installed version for Ubuntu 18.10 (Konqueror Version 5.0.97). See [Konqueror](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361177/how-to-switch-pane-in-dolphin-using-keyboard/390673#390673) and https://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=44064.0

Answer (score 0):

Dolphin (KDE) has a split view ("Preview pane").
Downsides: Only first page is shown and not as clear as for example PDF XChange on Windows.